# nc: Proxy error: "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"

Tags: ssh, proxy, openssh

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64. I am not able to ssh over proxy to remote host.

When I issued:

```
ssh -vl hackep6t 162.251.80.25
```

I got this output:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/rootkea/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec nc -X connect -x 192.168.5.254:3128 162.251.80.25 22
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1
nc: Proxy error: "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to proxy the SSH connection over a squid HTTP proxy, see your proxy command:

```
connect -x 192.168.5.254:3128 162.251.80.25 22
```

The HTTP proxy is the one refusing your connection. You'd have to look at that server's configuration (or ask the administator) to see why it's rejecting your attempts.